# bootstrap modal reload page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

burger icon on top. I have used bootstrap modal for menu..

When u click on burger icon it will open model having links. That modal contains close button(x). When u click on close button it redirect to on top of website.

When u click on links on modal right now its reload whole page and then redirect to that particular link.

My problem is: when u click on that link it should redirect to partical link without reload.

difficulties to solve this task:

1. When you fire same event like close button on that links it will redirect on top of website.
2. on click that link if you manually close popup by css ,whole site goes in backdrop mode(fade in). And if u manually remove that backdrop mode than scroll bar not works.

Current code in that website:

When click on link ,id of that division will be passed to function and then manually remove popup modal ,then reload whole page and then redirected to that particular Id.

My problem. : i dnt want to reload page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want:

```
<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $('#btnGoTo')
                .click(function () {
                    $('#loginModal').modal('toggle');
                });
        });
</script>

<button class="btn btn-success" data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1">
    <a id="btnGoTo" class="btn btn-success" href="#goTo">Klick me</a>
</div>

<div id="goTo">
    go to text
</div>
```

When you click on the link in the modal the modal closes and the browser goes to the div with the id "goTo" without reloading the page.
For styling the modal you can use the modal-dialog, modal-content and modal-header bootstrap class